# Ajax Autocomplete in Jquery could not showing result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        src = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
        // Load the cities straight from the server, passing the country as an extra param
        $("#k").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        k       : request.term,
                        dict    : $("#dict").val(),
                        action  :"autocomplete_dict"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item.value;
                        }))
                    }
                });
            },
            // optional (if other layers overlap autocomplete list)
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
                $(".ui-autocomplete-loading").css("background:url",'img/indicator.gif no-repeat right center');
            },
            min_length: 3
        });
        });
```

The anwer form server

```
["Lebemann","Leben","leben","lebend","lebendig"]
```

I can see the request from my browser to server but it could not showing the result form server. Sommeone can help me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried console.log(data)? I don't know if this is the problem you are having but you didn't json.parse(data) either so you are just mapping a string

Comment: I have try at this post : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp but it's not work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this. Your problem is common among developers new to jQuery. $.ajax is an **async** function meaning it is a non-blocking task. The function itself completes long before any data is returned. What I think you have to do is time it so you know there is something in the data argument.

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        k       : request.term,
                        dict    : $("#dict").val(),
                        action  :"autocomplete_dict"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#K").autocomplete({
                  Source:data // not sure what Response is but you may need to Response data if its a transformer of some sort.
})
                        }))
                    }
                });
```

This fires the ajax first, then as soon as the request completes it starts up autocomplete with real data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an item on your success function.

try it:

```
...
success: function( data ) {
    response(data);
}
```

this is can work!

Comment: $.map is returning data, not the success function

Comment: @quynt your problem is probably in the response function. Post that up there.